# What is the alternative to PackageAdmin.getFragments

Tags: osgi, osgi-fragment

With OSGi 4.3, I understand `PackageAdmin` has been deprecated. How do you then find the fragments for a specific bundle - i.e. what is the alternative to `PackageAdmin.getFragments(Bundle bundle)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the BundleWiring API to find the provided wires in the `osgi.wiring.host` namespace:

```java
BundleWiring myWiring = myBundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);
List<BundleWire> wires = myWiring.getProvidedWires(HostNamespace.HOST_NAMESPACE);
for (BundleWire wire : wires) {
    Bundle fragment = wire.getRequirerWiring().getBundle();
}
```

Comment: Not to worry. I just wanted to test the solution first to ensure that it works properly! And of cause it does :-) Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tonny, I just noticed this morning that this exact use-case is given as an example in the specification! See R4.3 core spec, section 7.2.3 :-)